# Why Wont This Code Snip Something From A String

Tags: c#, string

So I have data which has data separated by ", ". I am trying to separate the different data using Substring.

```
input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(", ") + 2, input.Length - input.IndexOf(", ") + 2);
```

In this scenario, I have already read the first piece of data and I am trying to cut it off. In order to do this, I take the index of the first instance of ", " and add 2 to it, which gives me the end index of the phrase. Then I take the length of the entire string and subtract the last index of the first ", ". This gives me the length from the end of ", " to the end of the string. This is what I want to snip. For some reason, I keep getting an ArgumentOutOfRange exception when this piece of code runs. If someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, it would be very helpful.

Comment: `var separatedData = input.Split(', ').Skip(1);`

Comment: You should show the starting value of `input`, and the exception message you're getting.

Comment: *"For some reason, I keep getting an ArgumentOutOfRange"* -- one of the arguments is out of range. That's the reason. The solution is to find out *what the arguments are*, and then read the documentation to find out what the acceptable ranges are.

Comment: You seem to be forgetting order of operations - if you want to subtract the index of `", "` + 2 from the length, then you need to add parenthesis around the addition: `input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(", ") + 2, input.Length - (input.IndexOf(", ") + 2));`. For example, if Length = 50 and index of `,` is 10, you are currently doing: `50 - 10 + 2`, which is `40 + 2 = 42`. What you want to do is: `50 - (10 + 2)`, which is `50 - 12 = 38`

Answer (score 0):

> Then I take the length of the entire string and subtract the last
>   index of the first ", ".

Not so - you forgot parenthesis around `input.IndexOf(", ") + 2`. Your intention was to do this:

```
input = input.Substring(
    input.IndexOf(", ") + 2, 
    input.Length - (input.IndexOf(", ") + 2)); // < note additional "()"
```

If you were not trying to put everything into one line - you could have avoided this problem:

```
var idx = input.IndexOf(", ") + 2;
input = input.Substring(idx, input.Length - idx);
```

You can also use `Remove` to achieve the same result:

```
input = input.Remove(0, input.IndexOf(", ") + 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip